# PgAdmin III, Windows - can't see database trigger functions when creating an event trigger

Tags: pgadmin, database-trigger

I have a database that looks like this:

[image: The database]

As you can see, I have defined a trigger function Balance_check.

I would like to now create an event trigger which calls that functon. However, when using Pgadmin's event trigger creation wizard, my trigger function does not appear, like so:

[image: Can't see my trigger]

What is the cause of this issue? Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong? I have tried typing the function name in various forms, such as:

- Balance_check
- Balance_check()
- Public.Balance_check
- Public.Balance_check()

But none of those make the "OK" button clickable, as I "Haven't specified a trigger function name". If I use the SQL tab, uncheck read only, and define the trigger in pure SQL, I still can't press the "OK" button..

The version of my pgAdmin III is 1.22.1

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, I was checking the wrong trigger. I had to go to tables->mytable->triggers and create the trigger there.